# How to split a string to get desired integer value?

Tags: c#, string, split

I have the following string,

```
var fee = "Receipt No: 000203680000140052568711 Amount: AED 53.00";
```

How can i get only "53.00" value from the above string?
so `int amount=53;`..
please help me?
I am using `c#`.

Comment: For _that_ string? `fee.Substring(49)`

Comment: yes last word. but length of the string will change, not constant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just split and take the last item:

```
  String fee =  "Receipt No: 000203680000140052568711 Amount: AED 53.00";
  String[] words = fee.Split();
  String aed = words[words.Length - 1]; // <- "53.00"
```

Comment: great worked . thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this will do the trick.

```
var fee = "Receipt No: 000203680000140052568711 Amount: AED 53.00";
float amount = float.Parse(fee.Substring(fee.LastIndexOf(' ') + 1));
```

Answer (score 1):

[Regular expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Something like the following should do it.

```
Regex.Match(".*(\d+[.]\d+)$").Groups[1].Value
```

In the above expression the $ means we are looking for the end of string. The parenthesis gives us a group. We want group 1 because group 0 is the entire string. The \d+ gives us one or more digits. [.] looks for the decimal point. The .* may not be necessary and actually may make this greedy to the point of a non-match. I have not tested this expression.